# Proper Layering in HTML

Tags: html, css

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPqQ2.png)

In the above image i want the dark blue div to show over the buy now button, like it does for the images,
I tried adjusting the z index for both of them, but that does seem to work, if i enter `z index -1` for the buy now button it just completely removes it from display.
Instead i entered `z index:9967` for the dark blue div,but that also doesn't work.

here is the css for the dark blue div

```
.view-side{
z-index: 9967;}
```

Html for button

```
<div className="action" >
 <button className="action-buy">Buy Now</button>
 <button className="action-add">Add to Cart</button>
 </div>
```

Html for div

```
<aside className="view-side">
  <h3>Category</h3>
  <button onClick={closeMenu} className="close">x</button>
  <ul>
   <li>Pants</li>
   <li>Shirts</li>
   </ul>
  </aside>
```

How do i solve this issue

Comment: We need to see the HTML and the CSS for div and buttons. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: is this ok? button css only has border-radius and background color

Comment: yes, it is not transparent, as u can see it is hiding the image, but not the buttons

Comment: That's still not enough code, but I'm going to guess here. `z-index` doesn't work unless a `position` property is set as well. So add `position: relative` or `absolute` or whatever  `.view-side`